# Cassandra-CqlEngine : Select some fields from CF not all

Tags: cassandra, cql

I know if I want to do this query by cqlengine:
    select * from test
I should make a model to test table then do this:
    testModel.objects.all()

this code will return all columns in test table but what if I want to do this:
    select field1 from test

Is there any way to select optional fields from a table by cqlengine or I should have all column in query?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method [values_list()](http://cqlengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/queryset.html#values-lists) method on a queryset in cqlengine to just retrieve the specified values.  Simply include the names of the columns to retrieve as string arguments.

So you could do something like:

```
field1_list = MyModel.objects.all().values_list('field1')
```